# Python: how to test if potential variable names are in the namespace?

Tags: python, namespaces

How do I test which elements of a list of potential variable names are in the namespace? Should I just initialise them as None or is their a better way?

```
# Potential list. Won't work, will give NameError if one of them is not in the namespace
all_vars = [rds.rclass, \
           rds.rlevel, \
           rds.seg \] # the list is actually much longer

#Could do:
all_vars =[]
try:
   all_vars.append(rds.rclass)
except NameError:
   pass
....

#or as initially said:
rds.rclass = rds.rlevel = ... = None
```

Is there a another (better) way?

Comment: Why do you need that? Generally, you should already know whether an object has the attributes you need.

Comment: It's quite a complicated program with lot's of classes and lot's of user choices so I thought it would be easier to check in the end which variables exist rather than tracking them down.

Comment: It's almost certainly better to refactor in a way that makes such checking unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, I guess I get your point.

Comment: I can't follow what you're asking for here. Which namespace are you trying to examine, rds or the locals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

horrid, but this should work:

```
all_vars = locals().get('all_vars', [])
```